# Quotation marks in "call it [something] for short"

Tags: punctuation, writing-style, quotation-marks

It seems that many (most of?) newspapers and journals don't use quotation marks in constructions like "call it [something] for short". Or even italic. Is it really okay to keep it plain?

No quotation marks, no italic:

- Let's call it ACG for short. - Independent
- Properly speaking, marc is the mass of pulpy leftovers; officially, the distillate is eau de vie de marc, but people call it marc for short. - The New York Times - Food
- The organizers hope that Smorgasburg (call it Smorg for short) will become a weekly addiction that ramps up the connection between upstate farmers and city purveyors of high-quality local food, and celebrates the borough's chauvinism. - The New York Times
- We call it spectral ridge for short. - EURASIP Journal on Audio, Speech, and Music Processing

Quotation marks:

- No, we can't pronounce it either, preferring to simply call it "OB" for short. - Huffington Post
- The overwhelming question on the mind of the hiring manager as she scans your material is, "What's In it For Me?" Let's call it "WIFM" for short. - Science Magazine

Comment: There is an ongoing tendency to use minimal punctuation. 'OK' is an ill-defined term hereabouts (as per usual). Many style guides will still demand (if that's the correct term) the traditional offsetting (though they may come to blows over whether this should be offsetting quotes or italics). Modern liberals would say that it's pretty obvious where a naming is taking place even within running text, so the traditional insertion of the clutter is unnecessary and best ignored on style grounds. I still offset in such cases; there are examples where complications _would_ ensue, so I aim for ...

Comment: ... consistency.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth This would make a perfectly good answer, imo, and I do recall someone giving me a schoolin' about respecting the ethos of ELU. :P

Comment: @Mick I can't remember the last time I answered _and_ close-voted a question. Here, I've CVd on 'answers will necessarily be opinions only (or say that answers will be opinions only) grounds. But you've prompted me to look for duplicates too.

Comment: Answered at [Use quotation marks after _that which is called_ and similar phrases?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/299759/use-quotation-marks-after-that-which-is-called-and-similar-phrases/299762#299762) (Jordan Stubblefield gives two recommendations.)

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I do agree with Mick, your comments are always very useful to me. Most of the time I simply upvote them to not clutter the site with something useless like "Thanks" :-)

Comment: The lead-in phrase of *call it* serves the same purpose as the question marks. It's the same as using *so-called*. With both of those, you've already signalled that what follows is to be treated in the same was as if the introductory phrases were *not* used and quotation marks *were* used. In most cases, only one or the other should be used, not both.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If a speaker clearly emphasizes a word or a term, should it be written down in quotation marks?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/471592/if-a-speaker-clearly-emphasizes-a-word-or-a-term-should-it-be-written-down-in-q)